# how to subscribe multiple sns topics to a lambda in terraform?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sns

i'm using terraform , to create a sns topic , and a lambda subscribed to that topic. Is it possible to subscribe multiple sns topic to same lambda?

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name = "test-topic"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "topic_lambda" {
  topic_arn = "${aws_sns_topic.topic.arn}"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. What's the issue? Did you try and got any errors?

Comment: @Marcin - do i just add one for each subscription , or is there a way to include multiple in one

Comment: Yes, you can use for_each. i would suggest actually trying some solution, and then updating the question with full code and error messages if any.